# Create View from logical File programmatically?

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

The question is about Logical Files (LF) on the AS/400 and views, by IBM i DB2.
I want to know, if there is a way, to programmatically generate an sql statement (or better, directly a view) out of an logical file.

For now, i look up the LF desription (command WRKF ..) and emulate the conditions in the LF.

My knowlege so far, is, that logical files can always be manually(by hand, so to say) converted into SQL selects... but if there is a pitfall, why there can't ever be a programmatic way to do this, i wanna know why.

I'm searching for something like an IBM I method for this, rather to script my own program for that.

Comment: Can you explain why you would want this?  Are you just trying to convert from DDS to DDL for modernization?  If that's the case, you'd be better off converting the logicals to SQL indexes instead of views.

Comment: I got the problem, that i want to incooperate logical Files into my SQL Views, wich is not working. So i tended up converting every Logical into an SQL view manually...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a programmatic solution but in System i Navigator go to the Schema you are working with and the Views section.  Any of these that are logical files you can right-click and select 'Generate SQL'.  You can select multiple and it will generate the SQL for all.  There is an option to write to a file.

Comment: It is true that you can generate a view from a logical file, but it will not be the same as the logical. The one part that is missing is the key. The key of the logical cannot be included in an SQL View.

Comment: So, as @jmarkmurphy says, you will need to create the index (for the key) and the view (for column selections, derived fields, joins, etc.) separately. If you are replacing an existing DDS logical that is used within an RPG program that reads it in key sequence, be careful - ORDER BY will always need to be explicit.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to connect a view and an index to use it in an RPG program with record level access (SETLL, CHAIN, etc). You have to change over to embedded SQL to use a View in RPG unless you don't care about the record sequence. Views are not keyed.